# Que puis-je étudier après avoir terminé tous les niveaux de Rosetta Stone?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, prononciation, ressources

J’étudie le français depuis de quelques mois et je viens de terminer tous les niveaux de Rosetta Stone. C'est un bon programme, mais je crois que j'ai beaucoup de mots et de grammaire à étudier, et ceci est la raison de ma question. Je veux étudier plus de grammaire et plus de prononciation parce que ce sont mes grandes difficultés dans cette langue. J'ai regardé beaucoup de documentaires et de choses que j'aime, et c'est une activité amusante! C'est aussi une bonne manière de améliorer mes capacités d’écoute.

Qu'est-ce que je peux étudier après avoir terminé tous les niveaux de Rosetta Stone? Je cherche une activité ou livre qui va améliorer principalement ma grammaire

Comment: Cette question n'est pas suffisamment spécifique. Si tu cherches une activité pour améliorer un point très particulier qui restreint fortement les possibilités, ce serait acceptable.

Comment: Merci pour les corrections. Pourquoi avez-vous enlevé mes mots "Merci beaucoup" et "Salut"?